# 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' in Assembly is not marked as serializable?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

This error occurred in asp.net & C# program:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' in Assembly 'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' is not marked as serializable
```

what is the reason for this type of error occurred?

Comment: Tim Schmelter sir,Where i put my code ?..

Comment: Edit your question and include the relevant code where you use that connection.

Answer (score 3):

Because you are trying to put `SqlConnection` in either a viewstate variable or you are trying to serialize the `SqlConnection`. The `SqlConnection` is not serializable that is why the error accrue. If it would be a class that you define yourself. Then you can mark it as serializable and then the error will not accoure. Like this:

```
[Serializable()]
public class YourClass
{
}
```

Reference:

- [SerializableAttribute Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)